# Is there an api or extension to translate IQueryable<T> lambda expressions to SQL strings?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I was reading an article on [Linq to Sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/12/understanding-linq-to-sql-10-implementing-linq-to-sql-provider.aspx) and came across this:

```
IQueryProvider provider = new QueryProvider(database.GetCommand, database.ExecuteQuery);
IQueryable<Product> source = new Queryable<Product>(provider, database.GetTable<Product>());
IQueryable<string> results = source.Where(product => product.CategoryID == 2)
                                   .OrderBy(product => product.ProductName)
                                   .Select(product => product.ProductName)
                                   .Skip(5)
                                   .Take(10);
```

The author then translated the results in plain sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t1].[ProductName]
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[ProductName]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[ProductName]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CategoryID] > @p0
) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p1 + 1 AND @p1 + @p2
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int',@p0=2,@p1=5,@p2=10
```

And I thought to myself, "holy cow! wouldn't it be great if there was an extension to IQueryable that would generate these strings for you when debugging?"

Anyone ever heard of anything like this, and if so, could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx

Comment: For background on what it's going to do in general, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Linq to Sql you can call `query.Provider.ToString()` and this will return you text of query (btw you can watch same property in Visual Studio when debugging).

UPDATE: (complex part) How it is implemented?

Actual string generation is done by `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider` class. It has hidden method `string IProvider.GetQueryText(Expression query)`, which builds SQL query text based on passed expression. This method is hidden by internal interface `IProvider`, so it's not trivial thing to call it.

Comment: @Rawling sorry, we can complicate it later :)

Answer (score 2):

I think [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) can be used to translate between SQL and Linq, hope that helps.

Comment: how would you do that with linqpad?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property to a `TextWriter` (e.g. `Console.Out`) to see the SQL *as it is generated*, but I don't think this lets you output the SQL *without executing it*.

Comment: You can also set it to a `StringWriter` that writes to a `StringBuilder`, or set it to write to a file directly.  Those are common alternatives to the Console.

Comment: @Servy: +1 `StringWriter` is one those rarely used types that are ideal for many purposes generally.

Answer (score 1):

A terrible hacky solution:

Use `DataContext.Log` as previously said, but just wrap everything in a transaction and rollback.  ;p